# Finding Lyapunov function for a stable equilibruim of a non linear system

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, stability-in-odes, lyapunov-functions

Given the following system:

$$
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
\dot x=y-x^2-x \\ 
\dot y=3x-x^2-y 
\end{array}
\right. 
$$

I need to find the equilibrium points, and if stable, to find a Lyapunov function.

I have found two equilibrium points: $(0,0), (1,2)$. By linearization I'v found $(0,0)$ to be unstable, and $(1,2)$ to be stable. I tried to find a Lyapunov function for $(1,2)$ with no success. How can I find such a function?

Comment: "I tried to find a Lyapunov function for (1,2) with no success. How can I find such a function?" Hmmm... Did you try the simplest candidate $$V(x,y)=(x-1)^2+(y-2)^2\ ?$$

Comment: Yes, that is what I tried. It lead nowhere.

Comment: "Yes, that is what I tried. It lead nowhere" Sorry but on the contrary, it gives everything one needs. How did you "try" this, exactly?

Answer (score 3):

Considering the surroundings for $(1,2)$ we have

$$
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
\dot x=y-x^2-x \\ 
\dot y=3x-x^2-y 
\end{array}
\right. \approx \left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
\dot x=y-3x+1 \\ 
\dot y=x-y+1 
\end{array}
\right.
$$

because linearizing about $(1,2)$ we have

$$
\left(\begin{array}{c}
y-x^2-x \\
3x-x^2-y 
\end{array}
\right) = \left(\begin{array}{c}
0 \\
0 
\end{array}
\right)+\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 -3 & 1 \\
 1 & -1 \\
\end{array}
\right)\left(\begin{array}{c}
x-1 \\
y-2 
\end{array}
\right)+O(x,y)
$$

now considering a local Lyapunov function such as

$$
V = \alpha (x-1)^2+\beta(y-2)^2
$$

we have

$$
\dot V =-2 (\alpha  (x-1) (3 x-y-1)-\beta  (y-2) (x-y+1))
$$

or

$$
\dot V = (x-1,y-2)^{\dagger}\cdot H \cdot(x-1,y-2)
$$

with

$$
H = \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 -6 \alpha  &  \alpha +\beta  \\
 \alpha +\beta  & -2 \beta  \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

with eigenvalues

$$
\lambda = \pm\sqrt{2} \sqrt{5 \alpha ^2-2 \alpha  \beta +\beta ^2}-3 \alpha -\beta
$$

now it is easy to show that there exists $\alpha > 0, \beta > 0$ such that

$$
\lambda < 0
$$

hence this affirm the existence of a local Lyapunov function to assure the stability of $(1,2)$

[image]

Comment: Of course, to be fully convincing in a teaching context, the $\approx$ step should be justified.

Comment: @Did I agree with you. I don't agree with the punitive vein.

Comment: What do you find "punitive" here exactly? Please be specific. Or not.

Comment: pleas explain how you got this :$$
H = \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 -6 \alpha  &  \alpha +\beta  \\
 \alpha +\beta  & -2 \beta  \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$ ?